# Can we add a Linux partition on a drive containing a Windows 10 storage pool?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, storage-spaces

About a year ago we had set up a Windows 10 pro machine with a 250 GB SSD and a  3 TB hard drive using the defaults from the installer.

The plan was to leave 1 TB unpartitioned for later use in Ubuntu. However for reasons obscure to me Windows 10 did not create an NTFS partition. Instead it had created a single 2 TB "storage space/storage pool" on that drive which of course can not be accessed by Ubuntu. The partition table is GPT.

From Ubuntu **gparted** all of the 3 TB of the drive shows as used up with an "unknown file system" for such a storage pool (German locale "Speicherpool"):

[image]

The Windows partition manager only sees the 2 TB "DATEN" pool. It appears to be unaware of another 1 TB of unused space on drive 2 (drive 1 holds Windows 10 and Ubuntu).

[image]

We can see all of the drive in the storage pool settings where it is aware of the  2,72 TB provided by the drive:

[image]

It appears that Windows had grabbed the whole drive when we wanted to give it a partition only. I understand that I could probably grow the pool to the maximum size of 2,7 TB but this would no help me in providing storage to Ubuntu. I also understand that we may not be able to shrink it later.

Is there any solution for this? Is it possible that we add an extra Ubuntu-accessible partition to the unused section of this drive?

Comment: Windows didn't create the storage pool, you did. I think reinstallation is the solution.

Comment: @harrymc; fair enough. If what I had done was irreversible we obviously will have to partition the drive with using a more traditional partition scheme. Will I have to announce the removal of that storage pool to the OS?

Comment: "It appears to be unaware of another 1 TB of unused space on drive 2 (drive 1 holds Windows 10 and Ubuntu)." - Is Drive 2 MBR or GPT.  Update your question to include this vital information.

Comment: I think you will be reformatting the disk and reinstalling from scratch, so the question is immaterial.

Comment: @Ramhound done. It is GPT.

Comment: @harrymc: if that is so then an answer saying: "no you can't add partitions to a drive where part of a storage pool resides" would help me and maybe others to stop searching for another solution and it would probably also stop people from creating storage pools on machines that also boot to another OS.

Comment: You are breaking new grounds here. There is no official answer, so it's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can not add a partition to a drive that is part of a storage pool.

Storage pools on storage spaces are for providing a pool of hard drives to the OS. The purpose of this concept is to have an easy way to replace a failing hard drive or to add another drive in case of low memory in a server. Of course this approach would be rather useless in a desktop computer where only one physical hard drive sits next to the drive holding the OS.

The whole concept of storage spaces is oriented to physical drives rather than partitions. This also is why we can only add or remove a whole physical drive to a storage pool. Also because of this we can not have more than one partition on a drive that was a member of a storage pool. This partition can not be read from another OS.

To be able to use the drive with a traditional partitioning, and to add a partition that can be read from Linux we had to perform the following steps:

> - **Warning:** removing a drive from a storage space will irreversibly delete all data on it. To date there is no known way to recover them.

- Made a **backup** of all files on the storage pool to an external drive.
- **remove that drive** from the storage pool. The graphic storage space manager would not let us do this with error `"Access is Denied" 0x00000005`. It could however be done from an elevated powershell with this command:

  ```
  Remove-StoragePool -FriendlyName "<Name>"
  ```
- Only after that we could also **remove the physical drive** from the storage space.
- We then used the **disk partitioner** to create an `NTFS` partition using only a part of the drive and left some unpartitioned space for later use in Linux.
- In Linux **gparted** was used to create an `ext4` partition on that unpartitioned space but we were also able to mount and access the newly created NTFS partition.
- We then **restored the content from the backup** to the NTFS partition.

Of course steps above can only be done if the storage space was used for user data only. It can not be done if Windows or part of it was stored on that storage space.